# Can I make virtualbox replicate its server to another machine for online redundancy?

Tags: storage

I would like to create a Vm server using a hyper-visor and have it replicated to another physical box so that if the main hyper-visor or Vm goes down the second one takes over. Is there a way to do this in virtual-box or another hyper-visor ? I have heard ESXi can do this but my hardware does not support ESXi apparently.

Answer (score 1):

For virtual box we have two different ways to replicate a machine to a different host.

1. [Clone a virtual machine](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-clonevm):
   This will make a clone of the current VM with, or witout snapshots. This will make the virtual machines identical except their UUID. The clone can then transported to another host.
2. [Teleporting a virtual machine](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html#teleporting)
   This feature allows to teleport a running machine to a different host in the network. Then the other host can overtake with little downtime.